# jquery do after the URL changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a 'like' system for my website. I've written this code:

```html
<a href='website.php#$id' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up like' id='like' ></span></a>
```

JQuery:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $(".like").click(function(event) {

        var id = (window.location.hash);
        id = id.replace("#", ""); 
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

It works for the most part, but if I 'like' one post and then a another it re-enters the id of the last post. How do I run the code after the URL changes?

Comment: where or how does the URL change?

Comment: Is the page refreshing when you click on 'Like'?

Comment: href='website.php#$id' $id is a php variable its being echoed out with php

Comment: no it is not refreshing

Comment: have no idea what you are wanting. Please put a bit more effort into explaining details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your spans have the same id="like" than only one will work, the rest will be ignored...ids must be unique..

maybe try...

```
HTML..
<a href="website.php#$id"><span class="like other-classes"></span></a>

JS
$('.like').on('click',function(){
    var id = (window.location.hash);
    id = id.replace("#", ""); 
    alert(id);
});
```

Alternatively...

```
HTML...
<a href="" id="$id" class="like"><span class="glph-classes"></span></a>

JS...
$('.like').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(id);
});
```

NOTE: again the id's all need to be unique... if this is not possible...change the above to

```
<a href="" data-id="$id">....</a>
and the js will change to..
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
```